# Jquery selectbox value update cakephp

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, cakephp-1.3

In my cakephp 1.3 project i am doing following.

```
<?php  
echo $this->Form->input('city',array('type'=>'select','label'=>false,'class'=>'input2','id'=>'city','options'=>$cities));
?>
```

And its my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
// var valid=true;
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#city').live('change', function(){
        alert(jQuery(this).val());                           
        window.location = $(this).val();
        $("#mySelect").val("London");
    });
});
</script>
```

Script action:onchange event is fired with select box and current page is reloaded with other parameter from selectbox.But pronlem is as page get reloaded,select box is again set back to default value.
   What i am trying to do is set value to select box.I am trying to do this with code:

```
$("#mySelect").val("London");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reloading the page, any code you call after the `window.location` line won't affect the page when it reloads. JS is not persistent. Try and avoid reloading the page if at all possible. Otherwise you could pass the parameters of the page along with the reload, and re-set them up when the document is ready (I really don't see any plausible application for this).

Comment: I have much more returning from tjat url wit passed variable...I got confused with decoding iterative json data.And setting it...I have used <?php $current_city = urldecode($this->params['pass'][0]); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">  
  // var valid=true;
  jQuery(document).ready( function() { $('select').val('<?php echo $current_city; ?>');
  jQuery('#city').live('change', function(){ //alert(jQuery(this).val());
     window.location = $(this).val();
   });   
  });
 
</script>    It solved my problem almost.But now i am having another problem.

Comment: Its that when i have this URL http://localhost/cityportal_v1.0/index.php/companies/city/London/page:2  then my passed jquery parameter is appending on that link and its become  http://localhost/cityportal_v1.0/index.php/companies/city/London/page:2/Germany   And i am really messed up with this actually